# Why is view autoresizing not working for the first time orientation?

Tags: iphone, autoresize, uiinterfaceorientation

After the view is loaded, I changed the orientation to Landscape. There, I see a blue strip and the view is moved down. When I go to other tabs and come back, it is working fine.

Can anyone help me with this?

I have done this to autosize the view:

```
-viewDidLoad:
{
self.view.autoresizingMask =( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin);
 self.view.autoresizesSubviews;
[super viewDidLoad];
}
-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

 return YES;
}
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe autoresizing is triggered before viewDidLoad, the behaviour isn't necessarily well defined. See if you can add your autoresizing mask option at the init stage (or even in interface builder if you're loading the view from a nib). Overall, much more info is needed here to help - but keep in mind that a lot of the stuff has been done to the view by the time it is in "viewDidLoad" (after all, it DID already load and ready to use).

Comment: I tried in init method.....its not working.... In other example i created a view, naviagtionbar and added (as sub view)to self.view. and set the autoresizingmask in init methos. when oreinted its the same case.THe view is appearing 2 cms below the status bar for first time.When came back from other tab, its from below the status bar ie working good.

Comment: Perhaps see if you can use viewDidLoad to modify its self.frame parameter to be at the correct location. You should be able to figure out the size of the window properly. Ultimately though if you're using the Interface Builder - setting proper autoresizing there should fix all issues. I really only ever set autoresizing masks like that manually when I'm creating the object from scratch (in that case it is set before the addSubview is called)